# Почему не получается получить все данные с Firebase?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, android-studio, firebase

Мой код должен получить все записи с узла в Firebase по идентификатору пользователя и установить его на textview. Вместо этого он устанавливает только последнюю добавленную строчку. Вот код получения? Ошибки не выдаёт.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        FirebaseAuth mAuth3 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String userId = mAuth3.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        database.getReference("users/" + userId)
                .orderByKey()
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                                textView6.setText(value + "\n");
                            }
                        } else {
                            textView6.setText("У вас нет записей"); // Если узел данных пользователя пуст, выводим сообщение
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        // Обработка ошибок при получении данных
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Не уверен на 100% но выглядит так, как будто вы обновляете value а не добавляете новую строку к старой)

Comment: @Binary, вы правы. Продублируете в ответы? Отмечаю решением.

Comment: Попробуйте `textView6.setText(textView6.getText() + "\n" + value + "\n");`

Comment: @NowhereMan, проблема оказалась не в этом, но спасибо